# Does Windows Installer provide a method to update applications?

Tags: windows-installer

Does Windows installer provide a built-in method for updating applications, or do I have to write this myself in my application code?

For example, ClickOnce can automatically update my application for me; I do not have to write code specifically for this in my application. Is similar functionality available in Windows Installer or is it purely for installation purposes only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Installer provides a mechanism for you to build patches and updates for applications you used it to install--either for minor bug-fix patches or for full version-to-version upgrades.  (Some information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370579(v=VS.85).aspx).)

It does not, however, provide an auto-update mechanism like ClickOnce does.  You'll need to write code that knows how to look for available updates and start the updating process.

Comment: s/to install it/it to install/, I think ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Windows installer does not but Google installer does https://github.com/google/omaha

Comment: I tried to use this, but it's very difficult to configure and looks like this project has been discontinued by google. Any insights?

Answer (score 0):

Windows installer does indeed provide a mechanism for updating applications. Check out this [overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370579%28VS.85%29.aspx) from Microsoft. Here are the specific types:

[Major upgrade](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369786%28VS.85%29.aspx):
For major new releases that involve wholesale changes in the feature tree of the app, and possibly the removal of outdated features or components (1.0 -> 2.0)

[Minor upgrade](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370037%28VS.85%29.aspx):
For minor changes to the application such as updating existing files and maybe adding new ones (1.0 -> 1.1)

[Small update (patch)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371855%28v=VS.85%29.aspx):
For very minor changes, typically with no change in the published version number.

Tools like [Wix](http://wix.sourceforge.net/index.html) help to author the MSI database that tells the installer service how to handle an update.

Answer (score 0):

While it t is true that MSI has various servicing strategies, an auto-update pattern is not one of them.  If you are using InstallShield you can use their auto update framework.  If you don't mind writing a little bit of code, here is one way to do it yourself:

http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2006/10/implementing-auto-updating.html